# PHP variable changes itself although not passed by reference

Tags: php

In the following code, I am having trouble understanding why the variable `$service_category_tree` changes by itself. Somehow, the `subscription_tree` alter's the parameter variable although it is not passed by reference.

```
$service_category_tree = $this->service_category_model->with_request_forms();
foreach ($this->view_data['users'] as &$user) {
    echo md5(serialize($service_category_tree))."<br>"; // To check if the variable is changed.
    $user->service_categories = $this->merchant_model->subscription_tree($user->id, $service_category_tree);
}
```

The output of the MD5 statement, as you can see shows that the variable is changed:

```
10066a31bb6e191fbb94b8dc61fd6e55
10066a31bb6e191fbb94b8dc61fd6e55
fd1e22aa74c048e88751c85528d23254
752e0cef4357d7a33e47b90ef207d396
8b5b6ea856080bf32b9bfecc4e43a3f6
8b5b6ea856080bf32b9bfecc4e43a3f6
8b5b6ea856080bf32b9bfecc4e43a3f6
3f3e7619e59e3776c395065e4278c3f8
3f3e7619e59e3776c395065e4278c3f8
dbfebae62d65bd04ce4ce74f2046f90e
34498709256b34ce4d843c1f735c4c6a
```

The method `subscription_tree` does not have an ampersand on the second parameter as seen in the following code.

```
function subscription_tree($merchant_id, $tree_array = NULL){
    if($tree_array === NULL){
        $this->load->model('service_category_model');
        $tree_array = $this->service_category_model->with_request_forms();
    }
    if(is_array($tree_array) && count($tree_array)){
        $my_request_forms = $this->request_forms($merchant_id)->result();
        $my_service_categories = $this->service_categories($merchant_id)->result();
        foreach ($tree_array as &$sc) {

            // Indicate subscribed service categories
            $sc->subscribed = FALSE;
            if(is_array($my_service_categories) && count($my_service_categories)) {
                foreach ($my_service_categories as $my_sc_key => $my_sc) {
                    if($my_sc->id == $sc->id){
                        $sc->subscribed = TRUE;
                        unset($my_service_categories[$my_sc_key]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Indicate subscribed request forms
            if(is_array($sc->request_forms) && count($sc->request_forms)) {
                foreach ($sc->request_forms as &$rf) {
                    $rf->subscribed = FALSE;
                    if(count($my_request_forms)) {
                        foreach($my_request_forms as $mrf_key => $my_request_form){
                            if ( $my_request_form->id == $rf->id ) {
                                $rf->subscribed = TRUE;
                                unset($my_request_forms[$mrf_key]);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return $tree_array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP objects are always passed by reference:

Thus lines

```
foreach ($tree_array as &$sc) {

        // Indicate subscribed service categories
        $sc->subscribed = FALSE;
```

could change the `$tree_array` object, which is a reference to `$service_category_tree`

You could also make a **deep-copy** of your array:

```
$new_tree = array();

foreach ($service_category_tree as $k => $v) {
    $new_tree[$k] = clone $v;
}
```

and pass it to the function. Or make a deep-copy in the function...

More info at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: I see, but the variable $service_category_tree is an Array and not an object.  However, within the array there are objects. How do I work around this? I am unable to clone $service_category_tree directly.

Comment: I have made it work by adding cloning the objects and passing it back into the array in the subscription_tree method. Basically: $curr_sc = clone $sc; Then, at the end $tree_array[$key] = $curr_sc;

Comment: The array are passed by reference too. The copy will be created, if you will try to change element directly, but in your case it does not happens, as you change the referenced values via `&$sc`. Don't change objects, if you don't need it. Or try `serialize`/`unserialize`